# Why there is no static class in Java

Tags: java

I am new to java. When I was going through language specification I found that static classes cannot be declared, but we can have static inner classes. I am little confused why we cannot have a top level static class. If I want to create a class containing only utility methods, I can go for static class. Any reason why developers of Java restricted this feature ?

Comment: What do you think it would mean if it was possible? Not a real question.

Comment: You should ask yourself, will you ever have more than one instance of your computer?

Comment: @Frederik Your comment is completely meaningless unless you are suggesting that 'static' at an outer level has some such meaning, which it doesn't.

Comment: @EJP You are right, I was suggesting a case that doesn't make sense to show that the OP's feature has no sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a restriction, you do *not* need `static class` to define a utility class, you only need `static methods`. For example the class `Math` in java is full of static methods, but the class itself is *not* static.

You might only need static class when you define an `inner class` that you want to use without creating an instance of the enclosing class, which is allowed in Java.

You can define your utility class as follows:

```
class Util {
  public static void method(){
     // your utility method
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A top-level class is by definition already top-level, so there is no point in declaring it static; it is an error to do so.

**[Static class declarations](http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/1999-08/01-qa-static2.html)**

Answer (score 4):

`static` is a relative term.

`static` means "independent of the containing instance". So a static field has the same value, independent of the instance of the class. A static inner class is valid for every instance of the parent class.

But what would a `static` top level class be "independent of the containing instance" of? There is no containing instance for a top level class. That's why it cannot be `static` (or, it always is `static`, depending on your point of view - but in either way, no need to specify it).

Implementation wise, a non-`static` inner class **contains a reference to the containing outer class**. Obviously this difference also is not possible for top level classes.

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't add any meaning. 'static' has a meaning when applied to nested classes. It has no meaning on an outer class. So you can't specify it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK,if it will allow the top level classes to be declared as static class then it will hold the reference in the heap memory all the time **even when you are not using it**.and that is what called **Memory Leak**.so that is why it is restricted to do so.

Comment: Answer is meaningless. Not entirely your fault, as the question is also meaningless, but inventing semantics that don't exist for a feature that doesn't exist isn't actually an answer.